# Cannot display Japanese in Pdf file after using by Laravel-dompdf

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-blade

I'm trying to convert a blade file to PDF format.

I've used [`barryvhd/laravel-dompdf`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) to convert to PDF but `DOMPdf` doesn't support Japanese font, all Japanese character display to `?` character.
My `php` code:

```php
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf/presaleorder', ['order' => $order]);
        $pdf->save('test.pdf');
```

My `blade` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>画像</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p> 
            ァ  ア  ィ  イ  ゥ  ウ  ェ  エ  ォ  オ  カ  ガ  キ  ギ  ク 
            グ  ケ  ゲ  コ  ゴ  サ  ザ  シ  ジ  ス  ズ  セ  ゼ  ソ  ゾ  タ 
            ダ  チ  ヂ  ッ  ツ  ヅ  テ  デ  ト  ド  ナ  ニ  ヌ  ネ  ノ  ハ 
            バ  パ  ヒ  ビ  ピ  フ  ブ  プ  ヘ  ベ  ペ  ホ  ボ  ポ  マ  ミ 
            ム  メ  モ  ャ  ヤ  ュ  ユ  ョ  ヨ  ラ  リ  ル  レ  ロ  ヮ  ワ 
            ヰ  ヱ  ヲ  ン  ヴ  ヵ  ヶ  ヷ  ヸ  ヹ  ヺ  ・  ー  ヽ  ヾ  ヿ
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I found a [post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-generate-pdf-wtih-japanese-font-with-barryvdhlaravel-dompdf) solved this. I've added `<style>` in `header`

```html
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
        body {
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
```

Now, all character display like this:
[image: Here]

But when I copied text in `pdf` file, I got this
`ァ ア ィ イ ゥ ウ ェ エ ォ オ カ ガ キ ギ ク グ ケ ゲ コ ゴ サ ザ シ ジ ス ズ セ ゼ ソ ゾ タ ダ チ ヂ`

I wonder, it's because of `barryvhd/laravel-dompdf` or PDF Reader cause this. I'm using `Adobe Acrobat Reader DC` version `2020.012.20043` and installed [`font-pack`](https://supportdownloads.adobe.com/thankyou.jsp?ftpID=5877&fileID=5913).

Anyone has solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I can solve this problem. It's because `Roboto` font does not support for Japanese. Instead use fonts which support Japanese. I've tried `MS Mincho`, `Hiragano Sans` and it worked.

A note that `dompdf` only support for font with format `.ttf`, so other format will not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Character sets**

You need to define the character set in the meta tag in the HTML document.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Comment: tried to add ```<meta charset="UTF-8" />``` but it does not work.